# UITextField moving when keyboard will block it

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to make it so that when you click the email field and the keyboard pops up it would move the view up. But right now with this code it moves the view up no matter what textfield I click. Also I cant get the keyboard to dismiss. Not sure how to set this code to only scroll to the active field?

code:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.emailField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.emailField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

I have a view that looks like this (it is on a scrollview)

[image: view]

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding.  It makes what you are trying to do really simple

Comment: You can check my SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16481347/2315974 for a similar problem.

Comment: If you want to avoid writing the code for this yourself, there are some drop-in open source classes that do all of this automagically, like: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: @savner I tried this and this works very well actually! I think the answer from Thomas is also great/simple and works as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can ignore the keyboard show/hide notifications and just use the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol:

```
– (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if([textField isEqual:self.emailTextField]){
        // scroll up
    }
    return true;
}

– (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if([textField isEqual:self.emailTextField]){
        // scroll back to start
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
– (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if([textField isEqual:YourTextfieldName])
{

}
return true;      // return true is needed.
}

 – (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
  {
   if([textField isEqual:YourTextfieldName])
      {

      }
   return true;    //return true is needed.
  }
```